# the means of phrase "take this thing for granted"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

what does this mean ?

> So we take this Internet thing for granted, but it's a pretty fragile physical system.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, watermelon. We expect people to do a bit of research before asking a question. In this case you could have looked in a good dictionary like this one: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-something-for-granted. If that doesn't answer your question, please edit your question to provide details of your research and explain what specifically you still don't understand.

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks. i did , but i can't understand means of this . for example now i know mean of «granted» and  other worlds in this sentence, but all of this phrase ,  doesn't meaningful for me. if you can , please explain means of this , in other worlds.

Comment: Did you see the link Javalatte provided? Sometimes, some words combined have a different meaning than each of them alone. This is one of those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about *our* (author used *we*) perception of Internet, about the nature of emergence of Internet .

Author tell, that there is a common opinion: *Internet is the same thing as water, stone, earth and air*, something *given to us*, or something *available to us* regardless of our activity; something, that will exist for ages in any circumstances and conditions. Then author told, that such point of view is wrong, and actually, the Internet is a difficult and sometimes brittle system.

PS: actually, Internet is not such brittle system as porcelain or autumn leaf or schoolgirl's self-esteem. Most likely, Internet is a dreadnought, or Human nervous system, or Indian rail network — enough reliable and self-regulating system.